# Dynamic text display

Tags: java, text, textbox, jframe

I am working in Java and am getting very frustrated with how needlessly (to my mind) complicated the system for creating windows and displaying text is. What I'm wanting to do is create a black box, maximized, on which I can display text (white font or any other color that is easy to read on black) and change the text during runtime. I've looked into Jframes and JOptionPanes but haven't been able to get it to work so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you've got so far and maybe we can help you.

Comment: I've tried lots of different things, honestly. At this point I'm back to the drawing board looking for the best solution. For now, I'll start with Ibrahim's answer and work from there. Still need a way to edit a JTextField's text after it has been created and maximize the window before displaying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **JTextField** with these methods : setBackground() and setForeground() . 
Or override the **paintcomponent(graphics g)** function of Jpanel and use the graphic class to draw text on it

try this

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class frame extends JFrame
{
JTextField txt;

frame()
{
    txt = new JTextField("Text goes here");
    txt.setBackground(Color.black);
    txt.setFont(new Font("verdana", Font.BOLD, 30));
    txt.setForeground(Color.white);
    add(txt);

    setVisible(true);
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    new frame();
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! This gets me a simple frame with black background onto which I can add text, but I'm not sure how I could add text after the window has been created. For example, JTextArea can be appended. Is there a similar function for this, or some other way to change the displayed text? Also, is there a way to maximize this window before displaying it?

Comment: you can use the method setText(String str); to update the value of the Jtextfield "for e.g.: txt.setText("new string"); "

Comment: you can maximize the size of the JFrame using the method setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

Comment: if you see my answer solves your problem please mark it as true answer.

Comment: Ah, I see what my problem was! I had no idea you could directly interact with the frame that way. I thought it had to be (FrameName).setText and such. Thank you for your help!